# How do I handle a button click event on an object from the page that instantiated the object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, delegates

I am working in asp.net 3.5 on Visual Studio 2010 and IIS6.

UPDATE:  I've added an SSCCE to the end of this question that demonstrates my issue.

I have a class that I call DialogBox that creates a sort of AlertBox on a website by wrapping a panel object and adding that panel to the current page.  The panel has an OK button.  So what I’m trying to do is create an instance of this class on the page and have the OK button’s click event be handled by a handler on the page that instantiates the class.  It seems to me that this should work…

In my DialogBox Class I have some fields defined like so...

```
private EventHandler _OKClick;
private Button _buttonOK;
```

I also have a public property defined like so...

```
public EventHandler OKClick
{
    set { _OKClick = value; }
}
```

The panel control has a `.show()` method that takes all of it's components and builds it all out before making it visible.  In this method I have this line...

```
    _buttonOK.Click += _OKClick;
```

Then over on my page, the one on which I am instantiating the class I have this...

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DialogBox Alert = new DialogBox();
        Alert.OKClick = new EventHandler(Alert_OkClick);
        Alert.Show();
    }
}
```

And I have the actual handler defined like this...

```
void Alert_OkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblOutput.Text = "It Works!!!";
    lblOutput.Visible = true;
}
```

The code compiles fine.  I click the button and the dialog box disappears as I would expect it to when the page posts back, but it does not run the code in `Alert_OkClick`.

I have been doing a lot of reading about Delegates and Events in an effort to understand the model.  I've successfully created an event on this DialogBox class that I am able to fire from my page.  But working with the button is different because it already has an event defined which I am trying to handle.  Am i just thinking about this all the wrong way?

Thank you for reading.

Here is an SSCCE

This is a class that wraps a panel object to make an alert box...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class AlertBox
{
    Panel _this = new Panel();
    Button _OKButton = new Button();
    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    EventHandler _OkClick;

    public AlertBox()
    {
        _OKButton.Text = "OK";
        _this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        _this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>This is an ALERT!</p><p>Press OK</p>"));
        _this.Controls.Add(_OKButton);   
    }

    public EventHandler OkClick
    {
        get {return _OkClick;}
        set {_OkClick = value;}
    }


    public void Show()
    {
        _OKButton.Click += _OkClick;
        page.Form.Controls.Add(_this);
    }
}
```

This is the code behind on the page that instantiates the class.  The pages is just a blank aspx page...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AlertBox Alert = new AlertBox();
            Alert.OkClick = new EventHandler(AlertOk_Click);
            Alert.Show();
        }
    }

    protected void AlertOk_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("EVENT HAS BEEN HANDLED!");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the handler fire when the button posts back to the page?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be here:

```
Alert.OKClick = new EventHandler(Alert_OkClick);
```

It should be

```
Alert.OKClick += new EventHandler(Alert_OkClick); instead.
```

Basically you register a method to respond in case an event occurs. You do not assign it like a variable.

Comment: I just tried this.  At first I got an error that Alert.OKClick could not be used in this context because it lacked a get accessor.  Interesting.  Alert.OKClick is a property tied to an EventHandler field, to which i was hoping I could just pass the event handler defined over on my page.  I really don't understand why it needs a get accessor when I use the += operator here.  I added it and the error went away but my handler still doesn't fire.  I'm going to spend a little time today stripping away a bunch of code and make a SSCCE from this.